# How do I set a material to an gameobject in unity c# script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to set a material to a game object in my game, I created the object in script so I dont have the option to set it manually through unity. All of this has to be in script etc. my code is

```
void Start()
{


    GameObject cube2 = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    cube2.transform.position = new Vector3(12f, -3f, -82.5f);


}
```

So I set the cube I created to "cube2". So aka what I am attempting to do is set it to red. I currently have a material created named red. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

First, you have to get a reference to your material. Either you use a public variable `public Material yourMaterial;` on your component and use drag-and-drop the material in the interface, or you can get it by code like this :

```
// in the Start() method
Material yourMaterial = Resources.Load("red", typeof(Material)) as Material;
```

Then, you can assign it to a GameObject with the `renderer.material` field :

```
cube2.renderer.material = yourMaterial;
```

N.B. :

I'm getting old... `.renderer` is obsolete, and one should use `.GetComponent<Renderer>()` instead as @Chopi suggests.

---

Edit :

For `Resources.Load` to work, your material `red.mat` must be in a `Resources` folder. If it is in a subfolder like 'Resources/materials/red.mat', then this would lead to  :

```
Material yourMaterial = Resources.Load("materials/red", typeof(Material)) as Material;
```

Comment: I was finishing my anwser with almost the same! :)

Comment: @Chopi, well, no harm from finishing it and posting it as well ;)

Comment: I am receving an error, here is how I did it  ; public class ObjectCreate : MonoBehaviour
{
    Material yourMaterial = Resources.Load("red", typeof(Material)) as Material;
    void Start()
    {
         
        GameObject cube2 = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        
        cube2.transform.position = new Vector3(12f, -3f, -82.5f);
        cube2.renderer.material = yourMaterial;
    }
}

Comment: This is the code: http://prntscr.com/j5nw6z and this is the error I get in unity http://prntscr.com/j5nwkd

Comment: Well, sorry, as the error say, use `cube2.renderer` is obsolete, and you should use `cube2.GetComponent<Renderer>()` exactly as in Chopi's answer !

Comment: I am using the given code and its now printing a pink cube? lol When programming I am receiving no errors but I run it I receive this one: http://prntscr.com/j5o1ek and http://prntscr.com/j5o1ii

Comment: That's because the `Resources.Load` part must be inside the `Start()` method. If you read carefully the error message, that's exactly what it is saying.

Comment: I moved everything where its supposed to be, thanks for you help. for some odd reason its pink?

Comment: that would be the red color with the lighting ;) you can try to play with the material. But that's not my area, and that should be another question.

Comment: Yeah I was playing around with it but its still not working. I discovered its because its not actually loading the material. I tested it with other stuff and I deleted a material manually off an object and it went the same pink... some im guessing it has something to do with that. is the Resources.Load folder like assets?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. looking at other Q/A like here : https://answers.unity.com/questions/881890/load-material-from-assets.html , you may have to indicate the folder in which your material is.

Comment: Quoting and adapting from the linked post : "You need to put your materials in a parent folder named Resources like this: "Resources/Material/red.mat"
  and then do : `Resources.Load("Material/red", typeof(Material)) as Material;`"

Comment: great :)  glad you did it

Comment: please @jonesmax give to Pac0 the valid anwser as he gave you the anwser and helped you during the process.

Answer (score 3):

You can set it from code using a public variable

```
public Material myMaterial;
void Start()
{
    GameObject cube2 = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    cube2.transform.position = new Vector3(12f, -3f, -82.5f);
    cube2.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = myMaterial;
}
```

As Pac0 said you can also use `Resource.Load` to avoid using a public variable, but in that case you will need to store your material inside the "Resources" folder.

Comment: It's still doing a white box. I dont think I'm using your suggestions properly...  My code is looking like this:                                                                        public Material myMaterial;
    Material yourMaterial = Resources.Load("red", typeof(Material)) as Material;
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject cube2 = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        cube2.transform.position = new Vector3(12f, -3f, -82.5f);
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material = yourMaterial;
    }

Comment: If you use a public variable for the Material, you can avoid using Resource.Load and assign it from the inspector. Just doube click in the "none" option and choose your material. Make sure that the chosen material isn't white :P.

Also I see that "yourMaterial" is been setted by Resources.Load, you have two materials

Comment: `GetComponent<Renderer>()` will get the renderer of the current game object, not the renderer of the other cube2 object created, if I remember my Unity correctly.

Comment: @Pac0 you are right!! I just have edited my answer thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

you have to put something in resources folder , and took it by it s name as the Unity documentation says https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)